# Как передать параметры в GET method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

есть такой метод который должен принять параметр ID, но ID может быть несколько , с помощью этих ID метод возвращает записи, как передать несколько ID в GET запросе ?

```
    [HttpGet(nameof(BasicAccounts))]
    public async Task<Accounts> BasicAccounts([FromUri]string[] id)
    {
        
    }
```

Comment: попробуйте какой-нибудь разделитель, который не встречается в id, get запросы не подразумевают массивов, хотя можно конечно и так `id1=x&id2=y&length=2` тут уже зависит как Вам будет проще их обработать на бэке

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43397851/5045688

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9981330/6808809 В двух словах: если сделаете `[FromUri] int[] id`, то можно будет написать `accounts?id=1&id=2&id=3`. Либо вы можете сделать свой `IModelBinder` и прописать уже так `[ModelBinder(typeof(...))]int[] id`, тогда сможете написать в запросе так, как указали в билдере, например `accounts?id=1,2,3`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да я использую это [FromUri] int[] id , но когда из swageer передаю параметры генерируеться такой uri http://localhost:8888/api/Home/BasicAccounts?id=12,32 вместо http://localhost:8888/api/Home/BasicAccounts?id=12&id=32, и в методе приходит одно значение "12, 32"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71061632/5045688